# Getting one field from response entity json

Tags: java, json, jackson, cxf, httpresponse

i need to connect to a rest service to get the user id by using a token.

```
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());

client = WebClient.create(properties.getProperty(URL), providers);
client = client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
client.path(PATH + token);
Response response = client.get();
```

The entity of response have this format:

```
{"message":"Token is valid","userId":1}
```

To get the userId, i have:

```
response.readEntity(AuthResponse.class).userId;
```

It is possible to take only the userId without creating an class with that format ? (without AuthResponse.class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to read your JSON as Map, for example: `response.readEntity(Map.class).get("userId")`

Please refer to [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#A.22Raw.22_Data_Binding_Example) page for more information.